# how to use ingestion inline write a Json into a table and not use the comma as a splitter in the Json

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, adx

I want to write below value into table use ingestion inline.

```
.ingest inline into table Purchases1 <|
{"19node_0x0101010002":{"values":{"nodeValue":"11139","timestampTssReceived":"2022-07-20T09:13:18.4590000Z"}}},xxx,30
```

but the json will be split by comma like below resalt, if have some approach to avoid the comma as splitter in this json?

```
.create table Purchases2 (name: dynamic, country: string, age: long)

Purchases2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the documentation ([ingest inline command (push)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-supported-formats)), inline ingestion supports `with ( IngestionPropertyName = IngestionPropertyValue [, ...] )`

You could ingest the data as json or as other delimited format such as psv

- [Azure Data Explorer data ingestion properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-properties)
- [Data formats supported by Azure Data Explorer for ingestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-supported-formats)

###### PSV

```
.ingest inline into table Purchases with (format = "psv") <|
{"19node_0x0101010002":{"values":{"nodeValue":"11139","timestampTssReceived":"2022-07-20T09:13:18.4590000Z"}}}|xxx|30
```

###### JSON

```
.ingest inline into table Purchases with (format = "json") <|
{"name": {"19node_0x0101010002":{"values":{"nodeValue":"11139","timestampTssReceived":"2022-07-20T09:13:18.4590000Z"}}}, "country": "xxx", "age": 30}
```

Comment: Thanks David, That's really cool!